# Can't add intentintegrator in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using zxing library to read qr codes. It works well in MainActivity. Then I want to add that code in a fragment. But intent integrator is not working for this fragment.

This is the code in QrFragment;

```
package com.myapp.agpj.qr;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;

public class QrFragment extends Fragment {


    public QrFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qr, container, false);

        Button scan = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bQr);
        final Fragment activity = this;

        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
                integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
                integrator.setPrompt("Scan QR codes in the school premises");
                integrator.setCameraId(0);
                integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
                integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
                integrator.initiateScan();

            }
        });
        return v;

    }



}
```

This outputs an error "IntentIntegator can't applied to android.support.v4.fragment".